# Python convert str variable to UUID type

Tags: python, uuid

I am trying to convert str variable to UUID type. Online tutorials point to below code

```
import uuid
delete_uuid = "5d27bf88-f3dd-4e95-89c1-f200c8484b42"
your_uuid_string = uuid.UUID(delete_uuid).hex

print(type(your_uuid_string))
```

but the output is still of type str.
Please guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get a UUID object as output you need to remove `.hex`, as [`UUID.hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID.hex) returns a `str`:

> The UUID as a 32-character hexadecimal string.

So, you can use

```py
>>> import uuid
>>> delete_uuid = "5d27bf88-f3dd-4e95-89c1-f200c8484b42"
>>> your_uuid_string = uuid.UUID(delete_uuid)
>>> type(your_uuid_string)
<class 'uuid.UUID'>
```